# output from popen doesn't capture the error return

Tags: c, linux

I was trying to capture the output from `popen`.

The command that I am using is

```
 timeout 1.5 ping -c 1 1.2.3.4 -w 2 | tail -1  | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2 2>&1
```

If you execute the above command in shell, you will get a message `Terminated`. My objective is to get the message `Terminated` in a buffer. I used the code below, but it didn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <errno.h>

char pingTimeToServer[256];
char *gateway = NULL;
char cmd[256] = {0x0};
char receiver_gateway[256];
char c[1000];

int main() {

    strcpy(pingTimeToServer,"TEST");

    FILE *fp;

    //snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "timeout 1.5 ping -c 1 %s -w 2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2", "1.2.3.4");
    //snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "timeout 1.5 2>&1 ping -c 1 %s -w 2 | tail -1  | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2", "1.2.3.4");
    snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "timeout 1.5 ping -c 1 %s -w 2 | tail -1  | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2 2>&1", "1.2.3.4");

    if ((fp = popen(cmd, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    while(fgets(pingTimeToServer, sizeof(pingTimeToServer), fp) != NULL)
    {

        printf(" inside IF .................. \n");
        pingTimeToServer[strcspn(pingTimeToServer, "\r\n")] = '\0';
    }

    printf("********** pingTimeToServer is %s\n",pingTimeToServer);
    pclose(fp);
}
```

Any ideas why it is not working ? Or if there is a better way to do it in C, that will be helpful as well.

Comment: The `Terminated` message is coming from the shell itself, not any of the programs, so it's not redirected.

Comment: Also, it only prints that message in interactive shells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is printed by the shell, and only when it's run in interactive mode. So you need to run a shell process with `-i` to get the message.

```
snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "bash -i -c 'timeout 1.5 ping -c 1 %s -w 2 | tail -1  | awk '\\''{print $4}'\\'' | cut -d \"/\" -f 2' 2>&1", "1.2.3.4");
```